# Query to Search All possible words

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, search

I need to write a Delphi 7 and mysql database query which would return the records including ALL words in the submitted name. So query will return records which has all those name words but can have different order.

For example, if search string is John Michael Smith, query should be able to return records with names such as John Smith Michael, Michael Smith John, Smith John Michael or other combination with all those words there.

As can be seen return only records which still has all words in name field but can have different order.
I can't figure out how to write a query for such requirement that I have. Please help.

```
procedure Tfrm_Query.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
mask : string;
begin
  mask:='''%'+StringReplace(Edit1.text,' ','%',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])+'%''';
  if Edit1.Text > '' then
  begin
    Adosorgulama.Close;
    Adosorgulama.SQL.Clear;
    Adosorgulama.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM stok.product');
    Adosorgulama.SQL.ADD('Where (P_Name like '+mask+')  limit 50');
    Adosorgulama.Open;
end;
end;
```

as a result;

```
edit1.text:='Jo Mich'; // Result Ok!
edit1.text:='Smi Jo Mic'; //No result
edit1.text:='Mich Sm'; // No result
```

Comment: You've forgotten to provide any information regarding the DBMS you're using, the components you're using to access the data, any information regarding your table structure, or any information regarding the SQL statement you've attempted to create. Can you [edit] to include those details? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing spaces with `%`, you could replace them with `% AND P_Name LIKE %`:

```
mask:='''WHERE (P_Name LIKE %'+StringReplace(Edit1.text,' ','% AND P_Name LIKE %',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])+'%)''';
```

Apologies if there is some problem with the syntax (I don't know Delphi), but if `Edit1.text:= 'John Michael Smith'` this should generate the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (P_Name LIKE %John% AND P_Name LIKE %Michael% AND P_Name LIKE %Smith%)
```

Which should find all records where `P_Name` contains the strings 'John', 'Michael' and 'Smith'.

Then, of course, instead of

```
Adosorgulama.SQL.ADD('Where (P_Name like '+mask+')  limit 50');
```

you'd do something like

```
Adosorgulama.SQL.ADD(mask + '  limit 50');
```

If the input can contain extraneous spaces, you will need to remove those first, otherwise this won't work.

Forming SQL queries with string concatenation could make your application vulnerable to SQL injection, just so you know. I don't know how to do prepared statements with Delphi, so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that can split the name according to space. Use the following code inside a loop that is looping split results.

```
Declare @sqlq as nvarchar(max);

-- loop start
@sqlq = sqlq + 'Select * from mytable where names';

@sqlq = sqlq + 'like ''%' + loopvalue + '%''';
--loop end

Exec @sqlq
```

Comment: I think you edited question. But you can use same logic on mysql with a little bit different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can build table of words dynamically. To find yours match do query that join both tables in possible match, and by grouping results test it - is name have all of words, try this:

```
WITH 
  words AS (SELECT 'John' AS word FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'Michael' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'Smith' FROM dual ) , --build your table of words (this is example on oracle DB engine)   
  names AS (SELECT 'John Michael Smith' AS name FROM dual UNION 
      SELECT 'John SmithMichael' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'Smith Michael' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'Smith Michael John' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'John' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'John John' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'John John John' FROM dual union 
      SELECT 'xyz abc' FROM dual ) --this is simulation of yours table of names       
SELECT name, Count(DISTINCT word) 
FROM names, words
WHERE ' ' || name || ' ' LIKE '% ' || word || ' %'
GROUP BY name
HAVING Count(DISTINCT word) = (SELECT Count(1) FROM words)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
Delphi + MySQL connection with word order with the following code, regardless of calls can be made. Thank you for inspiration. Respects.

Database model;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TableName` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PNUMBER` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PBARCODE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PSearch` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `PSearch` (`PSearch`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin5 ;
```

Psearch = PNUMBER + PNAME + PBARCODE ...; (Type in all areas PSearch)

Delphi7 Code;

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
mask : string;
begin
 mask:='+'+StringReplace(Edit1.text,' ','* +',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])+'*';
 if Edit1.Text > '' then
 begin
    Query1.Close;
    Query1.SQL.Clear;
    Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT MATCH(PSearch) AGAINST("'+mask+'" IN BOOLEAN MODE), tablename.* FROM database.tablename');
    Query1.SQL.Add('WHERE MATCH(PSearch) AGAINST("'+mask+'" IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 300;');
    Query1.Open; 
    end; end;
```